# Accessing variable of controller in javascript and assigning that value to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

How to access variable from controller to javascript?

Controller:

```
$scope.coveragedetailjson = $rootScope.getEligibilityData;
```

In this variable I get the JSON data. And I want to access the value in JavaScript and assign that value to the div.

Html:

```
    <script>
     var detail = $('[ng-controller="getcoveragedetailController"]').scope().coveragedetailjson;
     alert(detail);
    <script>
```

Then I want to assign this detail value to div. How can I do that?

Comment: get reference of Div using id attribute and use innerHTML

Comment: `{{coveragedetailjson}}` or am I missing something here? Why do you even need to do anything in your script, you already have that value in js

Comment: or `{{$root.getEligibilityData}}` if you want to be dirty. I don't recommend using the $rootScope unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Actually jsonAnswer is my div id for which I have to pass value of coveragedetailjson 

var data = $.parseJSON($("#jsonAnswer").html());
var coverage = new Coverage(data);
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px">
    <div id="jsonAnswer" class="jsonAnswer" style="display: none">
{{coveragedetailjson}}
    </div>
</div>
This is what I was doing but when I alert the value of $("#jsonAnswer").html() it just gives me {{coveragedetailjson}} and not the value @George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach your controller to the view with the ng-controller directive.

For example:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    {{ coveragedetailjson }}
</div>
```

this code bind the $scope.coveragedetailjson inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'assign this detail value to div'? 
This should insert detail to div -

```
DivElement.innerHtml = DivElement.innerHtml + JSON.stringify(detail);
```

But what you are doing is very bad design. Consider using data binding {{detail}} and if you need to pass it from one directive to another to it width Service

Answer (score 0):

In this you can directly access json data by key value and store it to div element For ex.

```
    <script>
        var detail = $('[ng-controller="getcoveragedetailController"]')
        .scope().coveragedetailjson;
        $(divelement).html(JSON.stringify(detail)); 
    </script>

Or You can do this  by this way

    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <div ng-repeat="x in coveragedetailjson">
            {{ x.keyname }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: <script>
   var detail = $('[ng-controller="getcoveragedetailController"]').scope().coveragedetailjson;
   $(divelement).html(JSON.stringify(detail)); 
</script>  With this it gives me error  - $(...).scope is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can use second way for print item in div element